# Indexing into cells using identifiers

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array

I have a cell array in MATLAB that is reasonably large with very mixed data called `sales`.  One column is a store identifier and that store identifier is a mix of letters and numbers (i.e. AF7-24M).  I want to grab all the rows in `sales` where the store identifier is equal to a particular store identifier.  I tried doing some logical indexing but I'm having trouble getting it to work...

I also would rather not just loop over all the rows because I need to do this multiple times and it's quite a slow process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html)... for example:

```
strcmp(sales,'AF7-24M')
```

For case insensitive string comparison, use `strcmpi` instead of `strcmp`.